# Global actions not visible on page layout

Tags: lightning, integration, global-actions, lightning-for-gmail

I am configuring [Lightning for Gmail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/gmail_integration/units/gmail_integration_unit_2) in sandbox. I have created [Email application publisher layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=outlookcrm_side_panel_set_up_publisher.htm&type=5) and have added the actions as show below

[image]

But in the Gmail I only see "New Contract" button. Where are the other buttons? (see below snap)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were two things related to the problem, try **Solution-1** and if you still don't see the actions then **Solution-2** should do it (as was the case with me).

#### [1 - Add "New Task/Event/Email" buttons to the object Page layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activitytimeline_configure_call_task_event_tabs.htm&type=5)

- View the page layout for the object you want to update. Make sure
  buttons for New Task, New Event, Log a Call, and Send an Email (not
  Send Email) are added to the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning
  Experience Actions section of the page layout.
- Make sure your users have permission to create new tasks and events,
  log calls, and send email.

#### [2- Edit Change global actions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181814/new-task-action-missing-in-lightning-experience)

- In the Lightning Experience, Setup Home | User Interface | Global
  Actions | Global Actions
- Click Edit next to any of the missing global actions (New Event, New
  Task, Log a Call)
- Look at the 'Record Type' pick list and select any value but **--Master--**

*Note: Solution-1 didn't work because I had multiple record-types for activities.*

Above solution is not only valid for [Lightning-for-Gmail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/gmail_integration/units/gmail_integration_unit_2) but also for LEX users.

Comment: solution #2 was the fix for me.